# Issue with az cli intellisense while using powershell ISE or Powershell Integrated Console in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I have installed azure CLI in my laptop but the intellisense doesn't work while using az commands in powershell ISE. Intellisense works only with Az Powershell CMDLETs. Any idea why intellisense is not working while using az commands and how to fix it? Same is happening inside Powershell Integrated Console in VS Code.

Comment: PowerShell and CMD share the same OS system. So does the IntelliSense work for other actions in PowerShell?

Comment: Yes it works with Powershell Integrated Console fine, no issues at all

Comment: So how does it look like when it works with Az PowerShell CMDLETs?

Comment: I am talking about using two files , one is a .PS1 file and the other file is a .azcli file for writing AZ commands.If i write something in VS Code editor in the .azcli file, intellisense works for few mins in the beginning and then stops working. I have to restart VS Code to make the intellisense work again inside the .azcli file. But this doesn't happen inside the .PS1 file where i have lots of Az powershell commands for ready reference. Inside the .PS1 file, the intellisense works fine without any issues and gives me option for powershell Az commands whenever i start typing

Answer (score 0):

Azure CLI's Intellisense or auto-complete feature is not supported out of the box on Windows. It only works with Linux Bash as of today.

If you want to auto-complete Azure CLI commands on VS Code, please switch to using [WSL Bash](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_opening-a-terminal-in-wsl) by updating your editor's [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows) file:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
```

[image: WSL Terminal in VS Code]

**EDIT:**

The Azure CLI Team is currently experimenting with enabling auto-complete in PowerShell ([Azure/azure-cli#13576](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/pull/13576)), although there's no firm ETA as of now.

IntelliSense for commands within `.azcli` files is provided by the [Azure CLI Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.azurecli) extension. You could try re-installing the extension on VS Code. If the issue persists, please open an issue with their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurecli/issues).

Comment: Intellisense i am talking about inside the VS Code Editor, not in Terminal. I have an Azure.PS1 file and i have a  cmnds.azcli file. When i write a powershell command in the Azure.PS1 file the intellisense works perfectly fine. When i try to type an az command inside the file cmnds.azcli the intellisense works in the beginning for few times but after sometime the intellisense stops working. So that's what i want to fix. I have to restart VS Code everytime to make the intellisense work again in the cmnds.azcli file

Comment: @Pallab Oh, I see. Do you have the [Azure CLI Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.azurecli) extension installed on your VS Code? If yes, please try re-installing the extension to help with command auto-completion within .azcli files.

Comment: @Pallab Any further update from your end? (P.S.: Updated my response above)

Comment: It's working now, will update you i case it stops working. I haven't uninstalled/reinstalled the extension yet, if it stops working again will do that and give a try

Comment: @Pallab Sure, if the issue persists, please open an issue with their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurecli/issues). Please [mark the response](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helps.